# Shortest way to read this file line?

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a file that consists of lines that look like this:

```
Alice 60 30 75
Bob 20 250 12
```

Where the name and integer lengths are variable. What's the shortest way to put the name into a string and the integers into an array of size 3? I did a getline() and then pushed the first char up to the first space into a char vector, transferred to string, then did the next char to space, converted using atoi() then sent to array, etc. I feel like there's probably a much better way?

I tried the suggestion line this:

```
int main() {
    ifstream infile("wheelgame.txt");
    string s;
    vector<int> a(3); 

    while (cin >> s >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2])
    {
        cout << "test";
    }

    }
```

But I think I'm misunderstanding? It runs forever this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A shorter way

```
std::string s;
std::vector<int> a(3);    // or int a[3]; or std::array<int, 3> a;
std::cin >> s >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2];
```

**EDIT**: Change the while loop to read from file instead of stdin (i.e. cin)

```
while (infile >> s >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2]) {
    ...
}
```

This loop won't run forever.

Comment: You get a +1 for using a vector instead of an array.  Better to use a [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) though if you don't need the re-sizing.

Comment: Thanks that looks a whole lot better. I'm forced to use an array because I need to pass it to a function that takes list[], but this should still work well. Can you still use getline() with this?

Comment: @AustinMW You can always just copy the vector contents to an array if you really need to.

Comment: @AustinMW The `list[]` is not a problem, just pass in `a.data()` (or `&a[0]` if you are still pre-C++11).

Comment: Or should I do `while(!file.eof())`? How do I move to the next line?

Comment: @AustinMW [Most certainly not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). Also: One question per question. If you have another question, just ask it in another question, not in the comments to an answer of your old question.

Comment: @AustinMW No, use `while (cin >> s >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2]) {}`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but are you saying to do that without the while(getline()) at all? I tried it both ways and it seems to run forever, I think I'm still misunderstanding something.

Comment: @AustinMW Update your question with the problem you're facing or write a new one.

Comment: Ahh thanks! I'm a beginner to file-io, didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

If your string is a char array and you don't want to use STL:

```
char str[MAX];
int a[3];
fscanf(file, "%s %d %d %d", str, &a[0], &a[1], &a[2]);
```